# OpenJDK JVM memory layout (Metaspace, Code Cache, Heap, Non-Heap, Runtime Constant Pool)

Tags: java, memory, jvm, heap-memory, metaspace

This question might seem like a duplicate or like a too much open question, but after long research I decided to ask it anyway.

I am looking for an updated (2023) overview of OpenJDK JVM Memory Layout, containing all important elements of the memory. I would like to be 100% sure how is the memory organized and where is the place of elements like

- Metaspace
- String Pool
- Constants pool
- Code Cache
- Thread stack
- Method area
- heap vs non-heap area
- and other elements which I am not aware of

When I try to search on stack overflow the answers are either old (still mentioning PermGen) or confusing, (saying some elements might be on heap and later answers say the opposite), referencing links which do not exist any longer. Same goes with google image search. I see so many images which are all different and never contain all elements, or show them in different places:

[image]

Is there one comprehensive image/diagram which will show how all memory elements are nested together in the memory?
I would like to eventually endup with something like this:
[image]

I wish to see the elements nicely presented. ( I can create the diagram myself of course with appropriate source of information)

Comment: None of those things are relevant to the Java Memory Model, as that describes the behaviour of visibility of data between threads, happens-before relationships, etc. What you're asking about is the memory **layout** of a specific JVM implementation, and some of the things you list (like generations/s0/s1/eden) are specific to the configured garbage collector, and not to Java itself.

Comment: @Mark I will rename the title and the conent of the question. Are the differences between the most popular JVM implementations so significant that they have to be taken into account? I have included the specific GC spaces because they were mentioned in so many documents and images that I thought it would be also good to put this section somehow in the picture.

Comment: Almost all widely used JVMs these days are based on OpenJDK (usually with no or very little modifications). OpenJ9 and GraalVM are the two exceptions to this that I can think of. Within OpenJDK you'll have to consider a specific GC implementation, as that quite significantly impacts the memory layout that's used.

Comment: @Joachim does the GC implementation impact also the non-heap elements? or the String Pool etc? I thougt the GC  would impact only distribution of objects eligible for garbage collection. Do you think it is better to remove  those elements(s0,s1,eden) from my qestion in order to have more clarity?

Comment: It certainly doesn't impact *all* parts of the memory layout, but things like which generations exist and how they are managed is certainly impacted by (I'd even say "defined by") the GC. So in a sense I'd say you can't find a single, up-to-date, unified view of the layout because many possible layouts can exist.

Comment: I think the definitive reference you’re looking for is https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/gctuning/index.html (for whatever Java version you’re using).